# Using CSS for Image Content?

Tags: html, css, data-uri

Can I define the base64 of an image in a class in the Stylesheet and use that class in the  tag? Dynamic fonts works pretty much like this, but wondering if I can do the same for image also.

The real usecase is to load an HTML into a WYSIWYG editor with Data URI, and yet avoid repeating the binary content.

A simple gist is like:

**CSS**

```
.mylogo{
content: base64;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img class="mylogo" height="" weight="">
```

I need to have height and weight etc attributes in the Img itself so that the WYSIWYG editors can resize image etc.

Comment: `img` is a self-closing tag and therefore has no inner content. You cannot use `content` to manipulate it. Also `content` will not even work in normal tags. It's only for pseudo elements AFAIK - see test: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/2rdd4mm4/

Comment: To add to what @Aziz mentioned; you CAN use base64 for `background-image`.  See: https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Comment: You can set its background-image to a dataURI, but then why use an img